# Unable to send multiple form variables using onblur function

Tags: php, jquery

Unable to send orderId variable to php file using this code please help

below is the jquery script i am trying to use but it is senting only one variable which has onblur option not other..

I am trying to send variable to change the value in database on blur but not able to make it

Plase help me get a solution on this at the earliest

```js
function submitPrice() {
  $("#loaderIcon").show();
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "updatestatus.php",
    data: 'finalprice=' + $("#fprice").val(),
    data: 'orderId=' + $("#orderId").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#order-availability-status").html(data);
      $("#loaderIcon").hide();
    },
    error: function() {}
  });
}

function submitReso() {
  $("#loaderIcon").show();
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "updatestatus.php",
    data: 'resolution=' + $("#reso").val(),
    data: 'orderId=' + $("#orderId").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#order-availability-status").html(data);
      $("#loaderIcon").hide();
    },
    error: function() {}
  });
}

function submitState() {
  $("#loaderIcon").show();
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "updatestatus.php",
    data: 'status=' + $("#status").val(),
    data: 'orderId=' + $("#orderId").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#order-availability-status").html(data);
      $("#loaderIcon").hide();
    },
    error: function() {}
  });
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr style="padding-top:15px">
      <td><strong>Current Order Status</strong></label>
      </td>
      <td>::</td>
      <td>
        <p><span class="statecolor badge badge-pill"><?php echo $row["status"];?></span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="padding-top:15px">
      <td><strong>Current Cost</strong></h4>
      </td>
      <td>::</td>
      <td>
        <h4>&#x20B9;
          <?php echo $row["finaltotal"]; ?>
        </h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <form action="" method="post" id="priceform">
      <tr style="padding-top:15px">
        <td><strong>Enter Final Repair Cost</strong></h4>
        </td>
        <td>::</td>
        <input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="<?php echo $row['orderId'];?>">
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Enter Price" id="fprice" name="finalprice" onBlur="submitPrice()"> </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </form>
    <tr style="padding-top:15px">
      <td><strong>Current Resolution</strong></h4>
      </td>
      <td>::</td>
      <td>
        <h4>
          <?php echo $row["resolution"]; ?>
        </h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <form action="" method="post" id="resoform">
      <tr style="padding-top:15px">
        <input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="<?php echo $row['orderId'];?>">
        <td><strong>Update Resolution</strong></h4>
        </td>
        <td>::</td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Enter Final Resolution" id="reso" name="resolution" onBlur="submitReso()"></textarea></td>
        <td> <span id="order-availability-status"></span></td>
      </tr>
    </form>
    <form action="updatestatus.php" method="post" id="statusform">
      <tr style="padding-top:15px">
        <td><strong>Change Order Status</strong></h4>
        </td>
        <td>::</td>
        <td class="align-middle text-right">
          <input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="<?php echo $row['orderId'];?>">
          <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control form-control-sm" onChange="submitState()">
            <option value="">Change Status</option>
            <option value="confirmed">confirmed</option>
            <option value="pending_inspection">pending_inspction</option>
            <option value="due">due</option>
            <option value="paid">paid</option>
            <option value="picked_up">pickedup</option>
            <option value="shipped">shipped</option>
            <option value="complete">complete</option>
            <option value="onhold">onhold</option>
            <option value="pending_pickup">Pending_pickup</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><span id="order-availability-status"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <td><a href="javascript:history.back()"><button class="bt_main">Go Back</button></a> </td>
      </tr>

    </form>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one `data:` property in an object. To send multiple parameters, use a single `data:` property containining an object with all the parameters. For example:

```js
function submitPrice() {
  $("#loaderIcon").show();
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "updatestatus.php",
    data: {
      finalPrice: $("#fprice").val(),
      orderId: $("#orderId").val()
    },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#order-availability-status").html(data);
      $("#loaderIcon").hide();
    },
    error: function() {}
  });
}
```

Comment: Tried with this but still not able to send parameter orderId

Comment: The input is missing `id="orderId"`

Comment: Thank you for responding ...
Bur Still not happening , i have added input id

Comment: What do you see being sent in the Network tab of DevTools?